# ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED with connected domain

Tags: iphone, browser, azure-web-app-service

Website, Application, Performance
DNS & Network

When our client using iPhone Safari, it showed like this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0feOc.png)

For some user (Iphone), they are not able to connect to our domain.

We do all clean cache, Reset connection, Restart, ....

Is there any solution?
Thanks.